# Allow a negative integer in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to allow following integers:

```
-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on
```

Here is the regex I was trying:

```
/^[-0-9]+$/gm
```

Here are the results:

```
-1   //true, its fine
-2   //true, should be false
-    //true, should be false
```

How can I allow range from `-1` to any `+ve integer`?

Comment: Why do you need regex for integers, wouldn't math be more appropriate?

Comment: Can be such integers a part of a string, like `someTe232xt-1kk33`?

Comment: @l'L'l input can be string too.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?:-1|\d+)$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI5iY0/1)

Using alternation we match either `-1` or any other positive digit i.e. `\d+` in the given input.

Comment: Not sure either. Since you beat me by 15 seconds, I'm retracting my answer :)

Comment: @JoséCastro: `001` is also a positive number

Comment: To clarify: I was merely trying to figure out why it had been downvoted and that was the only thing I noticed. The OP mentioned `-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on`, so maybe that doesn't fit.

Comment: In Javascript `01 == 1` returns `true`. If OP doesn't want to allow leading zeroes for some reason then use [`/^(?:-1|0|1\d*)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/nI5iY0/2)

Comment: @JoséCastro That is fine, I've to parse it eventually. I don't know either about the downvoter.

Comment: It is giving false for -1. And I tried even /(?:-1|\d+)$/gm. It is giving false for -1.

Comment: @AnishMittal: Not true, try `/^(?:-1|\d+)$/gm.test(-1)` in any JS console and see what you get

Comment: @anubhava: Hi Anubhava: I have found the answer and posted it. Kindly let me know, if you see any problem with that answer.

Answer (score 0):

More precise and universal solution:

```
^(?:-?[1-9]\d*|0)$
```

It prevents -0, 001 and other such variants.
Add flags **g** for global search and/or **m** for search through multiline text.